# Mac home network shows slow file transfer speeds

Tags: networking, router, mac, macos-catalina

I'm trying to setup a small home network for private use, but file transfer speeds are painfully slow. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

The setup:

A.) Late 2013 Macbook Pro (this acts as the "server")

```
 -Thunderbolt 2 to Ethernet adapter connected directly to an NEC router via Cat6 cable.
 -USB3.0 External HDD connected and is shared on the network
```

B.) Late 2019 Macbook Pro (client device)

```
 -Thunderbolt 3 hub -> Ethernet adapter connected directly to the router mentioned above. 
  Also using Cat6 cable.
```

So i fired up Blackmagic Disk Speed Test on the "B" machine and set the target disk to the external drive connected to "A" and i only get about 10MB/s.
I've also tried the same test targeting machine "A"s primary SSD but it also yields 10MB/s, so i suspect its either a network setting on one or both of the Macbooks, or something to do with the router. The router I'm using was provided by my ISP in Japan (im still in Japan), and its an NEC Aterm-719F19.

Some articles on the web suggested modifying the nsmbconf file, which I've tried, but had no success. Everything works fine other than the speed issue...

Thanks in advance

----Reference----

[Ping from A(server) to B(Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNsQC.png)
[Traceroute from A(server) to B(Client)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n2mC.png)

[Ping from B(Client) to A(Server)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oftoy.png)
[Traceroute from B(Client) to A(Server)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXt9n.png)

Comment: I should also add that both machines are running Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Can you try pinging between the machines first via IP address and show us the first 10 lines, also show traceroute between the two.  Your router shows support for 100MB/s. So it's USB 3 to computer 1 >>router >>computer 2

Comment: @MarkScheck Thank you for the comment. First off, yes you are correct: USB3 to computer 1 (the server) >>router>>computer 2 (client). Ill get back with ping/traceroute screenshots.

Comment: @MarkScheck I've added screenshots. Thanks

Comment: Okay so we know basic connectivity is good, Can you try transferring an iso file from computer 1's hard disk to computer2. I'm a command-line guy so perhaps SCP directly.  That way we can isolate whether it's the USB drive or the receiving computer.

Comment: @MarkScheck Just tried it in terminal with SCP and it transfers at around 9MB/s. I doubt its the USB drive as it transfers at around 70MB/s via the USB3 connection.

Comment: hmmm, let's see if there are retries and that is what is making it slower, netstat -s. Also, can you send me your complete scp command I want to check one thing.

Comment: @MarkScheck
The command i used was:

------
scp ~/win10x64.iso AdminUser@192.168.0.4:/Users/User1/Desktop/win10x64
------

As for netstat -s, is there something in particular i should be looking for? It gave me a long list of things and im not sure where to look (sorry im not too familiar with Terminal commands...) 

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Anything with dropped packets I'll install it on my Arch box (I think it should be relatively the same) We're looking for dropped packets and/or retransmissios. Can you test the speed to any other machines or even a speed test to the Internet.

Comment: failed, retramission, bad

Comment: @MarkScheck entering netstat yields a few hundred lines of text so im not sure im doing this correctly...at a quick glance the only "negative" entry i see is in the ip6 section where it says "61 packets not forwardable", and in the kctl section where it says "6 send failures".

As far as the internet speed, i tested on speedtest.net for both the server and client. Both machines gets roughly 70Mbps download and 60Mbps upload.

Comment: You should check what is the negotiated link speed between each machine and the router, on macOS you can use the command `ifconfig interface | grep media` (replace `interface` with the name of the network interface on each machine.

Comment: @SiavashSafi if his up and down is that fast to the Internet, I would think the only thing left is when it's writing to disk cache?? Leo try scpping a file the other way from the client to the server.

Comment: @SiavashSafi I tried the command you suggested but it says the device (interface) cannot be found. Perhaps because im going through a USB hub ethernet. 
In Network settings my interface name comes up as "USB 10/100/1000 LAN", and when i use that name in terminal it would just say "USB" does not exist.

Comment: @MarkScheck I tried both to/from client and i get the same results...a constant 10Mbps. Its interesting because the speed doesnt fluctuate at all, its as if theres a setting somewhere thats limiting the speed to 10.

Comment: Did a little more digging on the issue and turns out the solution is "suck it up and get a proper NAS". Not too excited about this but i guess ill go the NAS route. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Leo you should replace `device` with `en0` or something else depending on the interface, run `ifconfig` to find the interface name.